# Osnabruk to Amsterdam excursions

Tags: tours, germany, amsterdam

I am going to be in Osnabruk, Germany till August 23, 2012. I would like to take an excursion to Amsterdam. Are there bus excursion operators in Osnabruk that offer Amsterdam tours? (maybe some network which operates all over Germany).

Comment: Do you want to go straight to Amsterdam and spend all your time there, or are you looking for something that stops off at various points on the way there/back?

Comment: Both options would do. I am looking for at least one good option to travel.

Comment: That's a weird requirement: I doubt there's much of a market for excursions originating in a midsize town not far from the destination. Why not make your own way to Amsterdam (a 3-hour train ride)?

Comment: A person who will be on excursion has a limited movement abilities, so it is best to have a bus that just takes people from Osnabruk and carries them to several destinations in Amsterdam. Also, for me it would not be a problem, but for a person without knowledge  of English or German, getting around Amsterdam would be a nightmare. An excursion is not necessarily to originate in Osnabruk - it can be several towns around, or even a bigger town-based excursion, that picks up people on the way to Amsterdam. Most likely a person from Osnabruk or Hanover would know about such tour possibility.

Comment: Of course this is four years later, but I am surprised that you seemed to think Amsterdam is in Germany and nobody mentioned to you that it's actually in the Netherlands, one country to the west...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, I knew that Amsterdam is in Netherlands, I am surprised you thought otherwise after reading the text of the question. Probably last part "all over Germany" confused you.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: and the germany tag, and the mention of knowledge of German in your comment. But this isn't particularly relevant of course four years later, never mind :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that there's a direct train connection from Osnabrueck to Amsterdam Central Station, I'd just look for any tour operator where you can book Amsterdam tours separate from the ticket to Amsterdam. They'll just give you a meeting point that's well-reachable (probably Amsterdam Airport). That means you'll have to travel another 15 minutes from Central Station to the airport. Can't miss, really.